CUDA Error 101 with cudaMemPrefetchAsync Positioning on WSL2
I am running these snippets on WSL using CUDA 12.1.
snip1 returns a CUDA error 101: invalid device ordinal, while snip2 runs without any issues.
The difference between these snippets is only positions of cudaMemPrefetchAsync calls.
Is this difference solely due to the positions of cudaMemPrefetchAsync? What is the mechanism behind this behavior?
// snip1
#include <curand_kernel.h>

#include <cstdio>

void checkError()
{
  cudaError_t err_;
  err_ = cudaGetLastError();
  if (err_ != cudaSuccess)
  {
    std::printf("CUDA error %d:%s at %s:%d\n", err_, cudaGetErrorString(err_), __FILE__, __LINE__);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
}

__global__ void init_curand(curandState *states, unsigned long long seed)
{
  int i = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
  int j = threadIdx.y + blockIdx.y * blockDim.y;
  int idx = i * blockDim.y * gridDim.y + j;
  curand_init(seed, idx, 0, &states[idx]);
}

int main()
{
  int deviceId;
  int numberOfSMs;

  cudaGetDevice(&deviceId);
  cudaDeviceGetAttribute(&numberOfSMs, cudaDevAttrMultiProcessorCount, deviceId);
  printf("Device ID: %d\tNumber of SMs: %d\n", deviceId, numberOfSMs);

  dim3 threadsPerBlock(16, 16);
  dim3 numBlocks(8 * numberOfSMs, 8 * numberOfSMs);

  const int M = 10;
  const int N = 20;
  const int bytes = M * N * sizeof(int8_t);
  int8_t *noisy;
  int8_t *ising1;
  int8_t *ising2;
  cudaMallocManaged(&noisy, bytes);
  cudaMallocManaged(&ising1, bytes);
  cudaMallocManaged(&ising2, bytes);
  curandState *states;
  cudaMalloc(&states, numBlocks.x * threadsPerBlock.x * numBlocks.y * threadsPerBlock.y *
                          sizeof(curandState));

  /* ??? */
  cudaMemPrefetchAsync(noisy, bytes, deviceId);
  cudaMemPrefetchAsync(ising1, bytes, deviceId);
  cudaMemPrefetchAsync(ising2, bytes, deviceId);

  init_curand<<<numBlocks, threadsPerBlock>>>(states, time(NULL));
  checkError();

  return 0;
}

// snip2
#include <curand_kernel.h>

#include <cstdio>

void checkError()
{
  cudaError_t err_;
  err_ = cudaGetLastError();
  if (err_ != cudaSuccess)
  {
    std::printf("CUDA error %d:%s at %s:%d\n", err_, cudaGetErrorString(err_), __FILE__, __LINE__);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
}

__global__ void init_curand(curandState *states, unsigned long long seed)
{
  int i = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
  int j = threadIdx.y + blockIdx.y * blockDim.y;
  int idx = i * blockDim.y * gridDim.y + j;
  curand_init(seed, idx, 0, &states[idx]);
}

int main()
{
  int deviceId;
  int numberOfSMs;

  cudaGetDevice(&deviceId);
  cudaDeviceGetAttribute(&numberOfSMs, cudaDevAttrMultiProcessorCount, deviceId);
  printf("Device ID: %d\tNumber of SMs: %d\n", deviceId, numberOfSMs);

  dim3 threadsPerBlock(16, 16);
  dim3 numBlocks(8 * numberOfSMs, 8 * numberOfSMs);

  const int M = 10;
  const int N = 20;
  const int bytes = M * N * sizeof(int8_t);
  int8_t *noisy;
  int8_t *ising1;
  int8_t *ising2;
  cudaMallocManaged(&noisy, bytes);
  cudaMallocManaged(&ising1, bytes);
  cudaMallocManaged(&ising2, bytes);

  curandState *states;
  cudaMalloc(&states, numBlocks.x * threadsPerBlock.x * numBlocks.y * threadsPerBlock.y *
                          sizeof(curandState));

  init_curand<<<numBlocks, threadsPerBlock>>>(states, time(NULL));
  checkError();

  /* ??? */
  cudaMemPrefetchAsync(noisy, bytes, deviceId);
  cudaMemPrefetchAsync(ising1, bytes, deviceId);
  cudaMemPrefetchAsync(ising2, bytes, deviceId);

  return 0;
}


Check the return code of all cuda api calls to find where this error originates from

FYI: What is the canonical way to check for errors using the CUDA runtime API?

prefetching is not supported on windows.  Likewise, it is not supported on WSL2, which is dependent on the windows native behavior for UM.  See here.  Your question is arguably a duplicate.  snip2 "runs without any issues" because the api calls have no effect on the behavior of UM in that setting, and you are not checking those api calls for errors in snip2.

Does this answer your question? cudaMemPrefetchAsync() returns cudaErrorInvalidDevice - why?

Thanks to Robert Crovella, I understand what's happening. Let me quote the answer here.

cudaMemPrefetchAsync is not supported on windows or WSL2. That is why you are getting the error in snip1. see here. In snip2 you get no errors because your error checking is broken. See here.

